# How can I compare the sizes of a list of files and take the largest?

Tags: windows, algorithm, powershell, comparison

I've never written an algorithm to do anything like this, but I was thinking perhaps storing the file objects into an array or list and comparing them by sets of two and removing the smallest until there are no more to be compared.

Is this the method people typically use for this type of algorithm?

Example:  I have files A-E

if A < B then delete A else delete B
if B < C then delete B else delete c

etc..

Comment: powershell: `dir |? { -not $_.psiscontainer } | sort length | select -last 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly easier syntax:

```
dir -File | sort Length | select -Last 1
```

I find -File easier to remember than... Well, every other way I've ever learned of doing that.